# Find p such that P(X>2)=$\frac{1}{2}$ where X is a Geometric Distribution, Geometric(p)

Tags: statistics

I attempted to use the formula P(X > k)=q$^k$ but I could not seem to get anywhere with that. Would the q in this case be the $\frac{1}{2}$ and I just plug that into that equation or is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

**Reply to OP's query:** (too long for a comment)
You're probably substituting into the wrong [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) (or, equivalently, evaluating $\ \mathrm{CDF(3)}\ $, rather than $\ \mathrm{CDF(2)}\ $).

The equation $\ P(X>k)=q^k\ $ implies that you're using the version of the geometric distribution in which $\ P(X=0)=0\ $ and $\ P(X=k)=pq^{k-1}\ $ for $\ k\ge 1\ $.  For this distribution, $\ \mathrm{CDF(2)} = p+pq\ $, and when you substitute $\ p=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\approx 0.293\ $ into $\ 1-p-pq=(1-p)^2\ $, you get $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $, as required. If you substitute it into $\ 1-p-pq-pq^2\ $, on the other hand, you get $\ 0.35\ $ (approximately), so I suspect this is what you have done.

Comment: So when you plug p into that equation, do you solve for q then to get the 1/2?

Comment: The purpose of my above answer was simply an attempt to explain why you got $\ 0.35\ $ instead of $\ 0.5\ $ when you thought you were calculating $\ 1- \mathrm{CDF(2)}\ $.  I was assuming you had already correctly solved the problem by setting $\ q^2=\frac{1}{2}\ $, so there would be nothing more to solve for.

Comment: I understand what you were saying now. I plugged my p into $(1-p)^{2}$ and got $\frac{1}{2}$ for p = 0.293

Answer (score 0):

The "$q$" in your formula is $q:=1-p$. So write down $P(X>2)$ in terms of $p$ using the formula you have, and set it equal to $1/2$. Then solve for $p$.

Comment: Doing it this way I ended up with 0.293, but when I use that p for the Geometric Distribution and do P(X>2)=1-CDF(2) with that i end up with 0.35. I am assuming I did not plug it into the correct formula you were meaning?